# Trouble getting post variables from row-based elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on a "Survey" application in MVC 5. Basically it's an application to support surveys for users to fill out. The user can also go back at any time later on and change their answer too.

UI: I have a table with each row containing the actual survey questions, their answer (Yes/No/N-A, from a dropdownlistfor) and row-based comments. Their answer (dropdownlist selection) and comments for each row should be the POST vars submitted to the action.

Problem: I'm having trouble getting any post variables, which are always null. Here's some of my code...

ViewModel (SurveyResultsViewModel.cs)

```
[NotMapped]
public class SurveyResultsViewModel
{
    // ------ hidden
    [Key]
    public int EventId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    public string SurveyCategory { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Question")]
    public string SurveyQuestionText { get; set; }
    public int SurveyQuestionId { get; set; }

    public SelectList SurveyAnswerOption { get; set; }
    public int SurveyResultsId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Answer")]
    public string SelectedSurveyAnswer { get; set; }

    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Controller GET...

```
 public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        :
        :
        :
        List<SurveyResultsViewModel> vm = new List<SurveyResultsViewModel>();

        var Surveyresults = db.SurveyResults
            .Where(i => i.EventId == id)
            .Include(a => a.SurveyQuestion)
            .OrderBy(a=>a.SurveyQuestion.SurveyQuestionCategory.Id)
            .Include(a => a.Event);

        foreach (SurveyResult ar in Surveyresults)
        {
            var newVmRecord = new SurveyResultsViewModel();

            newVmRecord.EventId = id;
            newVmRecord.SurveyAnswerOption = new SelectList(db.SurveyAnswerOptions, "AnswerOptionText", "AnswerOptionText", ar.SurveyAnswer);
            newVmRecord.SurveyCategory = ar.SurveyQuestion.SurveyQuestionCategory.SurveyQuestionCategory1;
            newVmRecord.SurveyQuestionId = ar.SurveyQuestionId.Value;
            newVmRecord.SurveyQuestionText = ar.SurveyQuestion.SurveyQuestionText;
            newVmRecord.Comments = ar.Comments;
            newVmRecord.SelectedSurveyAnswer = ar.SurveyAnswer;
            newVmRecord.SurveyResultsId = ar.Id;

            vm.Add(newVmRecord);
        }

        return View(vm.ToList());
    }
```

Here's part of my View....

```
      @model IEnumerable<SurveyApp.ViewModels.SurveyResultsViewModel>
      :
      :
           <div class="ibox-content">
            @using (Html.BeginForm())
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SurveyCategory)
                        </th>
                        <th class="col-md-5">
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SurveyQuestionText)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SelectedSurveyAnswer)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    @{
                        int i = 0;
                    }
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>

                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SurveyCategory)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SurveyQuestionText)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => item.SelectedSurveyAnswer)
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => item.SelectedSurveyAnswer, item.SurveyAnswerOption, "--Select--")
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.SurveyResultsId)
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        i++;
                    }
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new {@class = "btn btn-white"})
            }
        </div>
```

The view appears to be displaying correctly. But, when I view source, I noticed that, when rendered, unique NAME values are not given for the "post"-related controls. I'm thinking that this may be contributing to the issue? For example, here's the rendering for one of the dropdownlistfor's....

```
 <select id="item_SelectedSurveyAnswer" name="item.SelectedSurveyAnswer">
     <option value="">--Select--</option>
     <option selected="selected" value="Yes">Yes</option>
     <option value="No">No</option>
     <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
 </select>
```

Here's my preliminary POST method. The var mySurveyResult is always NULL...

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(
        //[Bind(Include = "SurveyResultsId,SelectedSurveyAnswer,Comments")]
        List<SurveyResultsViewModel> mySurveyResult)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < mySurveyResult.Count(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(mySurveyResult[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer);
            }

            db.Entry(mySurveyResult).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

As you can see I haven't fully written this method yet. But, essentially, this post action will need to loop through each answer posted and save it to the db. I haven't gotten that far yet because I keep getting null for the post parameter.

Again, I'm thinking that the problem may be that there are no unique name attributes maybe? Maybe this is affecting the POST? Any feedback would be appreciated. Also, if you see (from my posted code examples) that I'm not doing things correctly please let me know.

Please let me thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `for` rather than `foreach` to iterate over your items:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].SurveyCategory)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].SurveyQuestionText)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(modelItem => Model[i].SelectedSurveyAnswer, Model[i].SurveyAnswerOption, "--Select--")
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model[i].SurveyResultsId)
            @Html.TextAreaFor(modelItem => Model[i].Comments)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This will give your fields names like `[0].SelectedSurveyAnswer`, instead of just `SelectedSurveyAnswer`, allowing the modelbinder to actually be able to bind the posted values back to a list.